# Does the SQLiteOpenHelper onUpgrade method actually change the version of the database?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Or do you have to do it yourself? I had always assumed that it did, but users are reporting errors that would be consistent with it not doing so. The docs are not clear on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to do this yourself.

As can be seen in the [source code of `SQLiteOpenHelper`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.java#L242), the database version is automatically changed after your overload of the `onCreate`/`onUpgrade`/`onDowngrade` method has executed successfully:

```
                if (version == 0) {
                    onCreate(db);
                } else {
                    if (version > mNewVersion) {
                        onDowngrade(db, version, mNewVersion);
                    } else {
                        onUpgrade(db, version, mNewVersion);
                    }
                }
                db.setVersion(mNewVersion);
                db.setTransactionSuccessful();
```

Comment: Fantastic! Someone who actually knows what he is talking about.

Comment: Why would the db version be changed in the onCreate() method?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky The version is not changed in on create().

Comment: @CL.  You said: "the database version is automatically changed after your overload of the onCreate method"

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky **after** it **has executed**

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not. The onUpgrade method is called when the DB Version is different to the version specified in the SqliteOpenHelper.

```
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onUpgrade(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase, int, int)
```

From the signature, you will recieve the old version of the current db and the new version you're trying to upgrade to. Usually the one you specify. You have to bear in mind that users don't always update every app you release so you need to keep alter scripts for multiple version upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

**No, it doesn't change.**

It is automatically called when database version has been changed.
Read more about that here : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html